# Pandas:iloc and reset_index are not being executed when its defined inside a random function

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning

I need to edit the given dataset by using iloc and reset_index.but the problem is i have 900 such kind of datasets for which i want to use some function to loop through and get the output..but when i defined a function iloc and reset_index are not executed...
code:

```
 def func34(frame):
       frame.drop(frame[frame[1]=='Banks'].index.values,inplace=True)
       frame.dropna(subset=[1],inplace=True)
       frame=frame.iloc[:,[3,4]]
       frame.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
       frame
func34(dataset)
```

Before function:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aapBe.png
After function:[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOe4t.png

Answer (score 0):

`inplace` [is being deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) in `pandas`. You should instead write:

```
def func34(frame):
    frame = frame.drop(frame[frame[1] == "Banks"].index.values)
    frame = frame.dropna(subset=[1])
    frame = frame.iloc[:, [3, 4]]
    frame = frame.reset_index(drop=True)
    return frame
```

and then

```
dataset = func34(dataset)
```

Comment: partially worked but the index values are not getting reset..ty

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `inplace`.
If you are slicing the df with iloc, it would make a copy of that slice, and you operate on it. the local variable frame is now this copy slice and not the original passed. If you are changing in the copy, you should return this copy and assign it back to `dataframe`.
One way around would be to access the slice without copying, i.e., avoid `loc/iloc`.

```py
def func34(frame):
       frame.drop(frame[frame[1]=='Banks'].index.values,inplace=True)
       frame.dropna(subset=[1],inplace=True)
       frame=frame.iloc[:,[3,4]] # <- new frame df that is a slice copy of orignal, but not returned
       frame.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
       frame
func34(dataset)
```

Comment: Everything worked if i remove inplace parameter except the reset_index for which i applied the inplace parameter and worked too... finally if i remove inplace parameter for reset_index but assign the copy to new variable, it worked too..:)